# What is this weird file shortcut in my Windows 10 startup settings for?

Tags: windows-10, virus, virus-removal

I just noticed it today when I was disabling other stuff, I've disabled it at startup now.

[image: startup app screenshot]

It's located here:

[image: unknown file properties]

Any ideas what it is ? it looks suspicious to me.

Comment: Looks like something went wrong went during the installation of an application, and the proper filename was not handled/written correctly. In any case, use your antivirus and scan your machine.

Comment: Doing a full scan right now.

Comment: What installer is located in the `Location`?

Comment: You can check with this batch script [Processes_Services_Tasks_Startup.bat](https://pastebin.com/ZvWS1XL6) the location of your suspect file